# Why maven-war-plugin behaves differently than the standard maven dependency resolving mechanism

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Is there a reason maven-war-plugin behaves differently than the standard maven dependency resolving mechanism?
I have a war maven project which has a dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>GroupA</groupId>
        <artifactId>DependencyA</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>GroupB</groupId>
                <artifactId>DependencyB</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

The above dependency is correctly excluded and I can verify on the dependency hierarchy view.
When I build the war with maven it includes the DependencyB in `WEB-INF/lib` directory, so I have to explicitly define to exclude it using the maven-war-plugin as so:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                <packagingExcludes>
                    WEB-INF/lib/dependencyB.jar,
                </packagingExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I have to do the above cause conflicts between versions arise on my project.
Why is this happening?
Is there another way to achieve this?

---

**UPDATE**

So I created a test case just to showcase you what I mean, if I was not clear enough before.
And the corresponding pom's are as below:

**ArtifactA:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>GroupA</groupId>
<artifactId>ArtifactA</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>ArtifactA Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>GroupB</groupId>
        <artifactId>ArtifactB</artifactId>
        <type>war</type>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>GroupC</groupId>
                <artifactId>ArtifactC</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
    <finalName>ArtifactA</finalName>
</build>
```

**ArtifactB**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>GroupB</groupId>
<artifactId>ArtifactB</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>ArtifactB Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>GroupC</groupId>
        <artifactId>ArtifactC</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>ArtifactB</finalName>
</build>
```

**ArtifactC**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>GroupC</groupId>
<artifactId>ArtifactC</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>ArtifatcC</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

In the dependency Hierarchy in Eclipse, I do not see the dependency ArtifactC.
[image]

And when building the ArtifactA and unzipping the .war I get:
[image]

As you can see the transitive dependency is included in the .war in the WEB-INF/lib.
I hope this is more clear now.

Some other details to add:

1. I'm calling maven from eclipse
2. maven-war-plugin version 2.1.1, also tested 2.5
3. Maven version 3.0.4 embedded in Eclipse

Comment: Is transitive DependencyB being included by a different dependency (not A) by chance?  You might need to exclude it in more than one place.

Comment: Please add you full pom. Which Maven version? Which version maven-war-plugin do you use? How did you call maven? From command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not so much that the war plugin handles dependency exclusion differently, but that it handles dependencies of `<type>war</type>` specially. It creates a [war overlay](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html) out of these, meaning it takes the whole contents of the war and puts the projects web resources on top. The war dependency really has no transitive dependencies, it already includes all jar files.

If using war overlays is really your intention then using `packagingExcludes` is the correct solution. If you instead want to depend on the classes in artifact B then you should modify the pom so it creates a separate artifact (using the [`attachClasses` configuration](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/faq.html#attached)) and depend on this `classes` artifact. Exclusion of transitive dependencies should then work as with any other jar dependency.

Comment: Thank you for the information, this gives me more insight on what is really happening. The `packagingExcludes` as already I'm using is my best shot since I rely on other things, not only jar dependencies and the `attachClasses` solution will basically exclude the `WEB-INF` directory

Answer (score 0):

I too have noticed strange behavior with `<exclusions>`. My best recommendation is to put this in the war project (Project A).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>GroupC</groupId>
    <artifactId>ArtifactC</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

**notice the scope `provided`**

I have to do this frequently for commons-logging as something always seems to somehow cause it to be included and its just a pain in the a$$ to go around and mark exclusions everywhere.

The other option is to do this in Project B:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>GroupC</groupId>
    <artifactId>ArtifactC</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Then add the ArtifactC and ArtifactB dependency explicitly where you actually need it (ie deploying B in other places).

**notice the `optional`**

Like I said in my comment I don't think its a good idea to rely on `<exclusions>`. It generally means something is broken. Its particularly bad if your the one causing it.

Comment: The `provided` scope for the depencency `ArtifactC` in `ArtifactB` pom.xml as you mention, will work(as tested) for the building of the ArtifactA but I'm pretty sure that will break the deployment of `ArtifactB` if you need to deployed it separately somewhere.

Comment: Well making a war artifact an upstream dependency is not a good idea. I'm not even sure if it will work so its unlikely that you would every deploy ArtifactB into another project (ie depend on it as though it were a jar). Besides exclusion is more of a hack for projects that have their deps wrong. It means something is broken. `provided` on the other hand means you already have the code or something like the code deployed (like servlet jars).

Comment: Sorry I meant put the provided on ArtifactA. That maybe where the confusion is (I got confused myself even in my last comment).

Comment: Yes `provided` is what you say "already have the code or something like the code deployed (like servlet jars)", but in this specific case is used as a hack, because setting the dependency `ArtifactC` as `provided` you make it unavailable in runtime because you expect someone else like the container to provide it. But actually nobody else is providing this specific dependency and you have another dependency of a different version in place.
So in my case this is not going to work since I want to be able to deploy `ArtifactB` separate as well.(e.g `ArtifactA` is a GUI and `ArtifactB` a REST API)

Comment: Did you try `optional` (my last edit)? If its not provided then it sounds like its optional. I just don't understand how ArtifactA doesn't actually need ArtifactC. If it doesn't need it sounds like an optional dependency. Either that or ArtifactB needs some refactoring into more artifacts.

Comment: The `provided` option in `ArtifactA` doesn't work as well. At first glace I thought that the optional might work, but it removes the dependency from the build of `ArtifactB` so it's not valid in my case. An example on why, can be that you need a specific version `ArtifactC` dependency on ArtifactB only at some functionality in the project `ArtifactB` and for you are not allowed to change that version for some reason and in `ArtifactA` you use another version of `ArtifactC` which has some extra functionality. Hope that clears the fog a little.

Comment: Just so we are clear if you did optional for `ArtifactC` in `ArtifactB` and then later depended on both `ArtifactB` and `ArtifactC` but an older version of `ArtifactC`, `ArtifactB`'s desired version of `ArtifactC` would win and be the one resolved in lets call it `ArtifactX`. Personally I like to explicitly require artifacts as much as I can instead of relying on transitive artifacts. That is if ArtifactX needs ArtifactC it pulls it in regardless of ArtifactB. Cleary `ArtifactC` is an `optional` artifact for `ArtifactB` since `ArtifactA` doesn't need it. To each in their own :)

Comment: Yes that will work but in the case of a war of `ArtifactB` the dependency `ArtifactC` is not included in the war if its `optional`. Anyway thanks for your comments! :)